Бот не обрабатывает callback запрос aiogram
async def AcceptFIO(message: types.Message,state: FSMContext):
    await message.reply(message.text,reply_markup=inlinekeyboard_confirmation)
    await state.set_state('ffff')

async def process_callback_button(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    code = callback_query.data
    if code == 'yes':
        response = "You pressed Button 1"
    elif code == 'repeat':
        response = "You pressed Button 2"

    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, response)
        
def setup_handlers(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(process_callback_button,state='ffff')

Вот код
Почему бот не обрабатывает нажатие на кнопку?
Вот код создания клавиатуры
inlinekeyboard_confirmation = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
button_confirmation = InlineKeyboardButton('Да',callback_data='yes')
button_repeat = InlineKeyboardButton('Повторить ввод',callback_data='repeat')
inlinekeyboard_confirmation.add(button_confirmation,button_repeat)

